# Laravel orderByRaw with postgres

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I working with Laravel and postgres. I have a code:

```
$users->orderBy(\DB::raw("FIELD(status, $orderedStatuses)"));
```

After running, I get error: Undefined function `FIELD()` in postgres. How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Postgres does not have a `FIELD` function (it only exists in MySQL).  You may `ORDER BY` using a `CASE` expression of all the status values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the second onwards parameters to `FIELD` should be valid MySQL literals.  In this case, assuming your status values are text, these parameters need to be CSV valid strings.  You *could* use `implode` here as follows:

```php
$items = "'" . implode("', '", $orderedStatuses) . "'";

// ...
$users->orderBy(\DB::raw("FIELD(status, $items)"));
```

Note that this approach may expose you to SQL injection.  Assuming the list of fields to be used with `FIELD` are relatively small, it would be safer to use just `ORDER BY` using a `CASE` expression.

**Edit:**

As you are using Postgres, and not MySQL or MariaDB, there is no `FIELD` function available to you, even with raw SQL.  So, you should instead order by a `CASE` expression, something like this:

```sql
ORDER BY CASE status WHEN 'start' THEN 1 WHEN 'middle' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END
```

Updated Laravel code:

```php
$orderBy = "CASE status WHEN 'start' THEN 1 WHEN 'middle' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END";
$users->orderBy(\DB::raw($orderBy));
```

Comment: Problem that in postgres no function FIELD.

Comment: @Jadasdas Oh...didn't know you were using Postgres.  I will add an option for Postgres.  You can't use `FIELD`.